# Problema con una SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tengo la siguente `SELECT` que genera una array JSON con objetos dento que son los hoteles.

```
    SELECT CONCAT(
    '[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', h.hotel_id , 'nom', h.nom, 'estrelles', h.categoria, 'puntuacio', h.puntacio, 'tipus', h.tipus, 'descripcio', h.descripcio, 'adreca', h.adreca, 'lat', h.latitud, 'lng', h.longitud, 'web', h.web )),
    ']'
) 
FROM hotels h
```

**El problema es que solo me genera algunos Hoteles, no todos.**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "lat": 41.39630126953125,
    "lng": 2.166100025177002,
    "nom": "987 Barcelona",
    "web": "room-matehotels.com",
    "tipus": "H",
    "adreca": "Mallorca, 288",
    "estrelles": 4,
    "puntuacio": 4,
    "descripcio": "Sus instalaciones constan de 1 bar, ascensores, terraza, recepción 24 h, cambio de moneda, servicio de lavandería, de niñera, una sala de conferencias de hasta 8 personas o servicio para minusválidos."
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "lat": 41.375999450683594,
    "lng": 2.1670000553131104,
    "nom": "Acta Millenni ",
    "web": " hotel-millennibarcelona.com",
    "tipus": "H",
    "adreca": "Ronda de Sant Pau, 14",
    "estrelles": 4,
    "puntuacio": 3,
    "descripcio": "A prop del centre de la ciutat i de la platja; botigues, llocs turístics, restaurants i bars a prop."
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "lat": 41.37900161743164,
    "lng": 2.169600009918213,
    "nom": "Barcelo Raval",
    "web": "barcelo.com",
    "tipus": "H",
    "adreca": "Rambla del Raval, 17-21",
    "estrelles": 4,
    "puntuacio": 4,
    "descripcio": "Mol bon hotel, bones habitacions i serveis.."
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "lat": 41.375198364257
]
```

Como podéis ver en el último objecto se queda a medias de generarlo.

¿Alguna idea de por qué hace esto?

Comment: ¿Tiene valores esos rows? Es decir, tiene nombre, web, etc..Sobre todo que no haya valores NULL.

Comment: Hay algun campo que tienen NULL, pero mucho otros no, eso es lo que no entiendo.. deberia mostrame los que no estan es NULL

Comment: Puedes añadir más detalle al titulo de la pregunta?  @MohamedA.B

Comment: Ya esta resulta..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tiene pinta de que el problema es la limitación de carácteres de la función `GROUP_CONCAT`. Tiene una limitación por defecto de 1024 caracteres. Tendrás que cambiar el valor:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Aquí más info:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791505/group-concat-results-cut-off

y aquí:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

---

A partir de [MySQL 5.7.22](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-22.html) tienes disponible la función [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) que puedes usar en lugar de `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id', h.hotel_id ,
      'nom', h.nom,
      'estrelles', h.categoria,
      'puntuacio', h.puntacio,
      'tipus', h.tipus,
      'descripcio', h.descripcio,
      'adreca', h.adreca,
      'lat', h.latitud,
      'lng', h.longitud,
      'web', h.web
    )
  ) json
FROM hotels h
```

[(Ver demostración en línea)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vP44vAfbzNBfr6Ay8kMzqe/0)

Comment: Muchas gracias tío era eso..

Comment: ¿Te importa si agrego información útil a tu respuesta acerca de la función nativa de agregado de valores JSON?

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la labor!